# Raise application error in a stored procedure when inputs contain keywords like 'delete' , 'insert','update'

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-11g-r2, security, plsql

I have a Stored Procedure which gets 6 input queries and the inputs are the same as `where clause` of a query. For instance `where x=1 and z=5 and e=4`. The Application makes these input strings and pass it onto my procedure.This is a part of my procedure in which I'm checking the inputs in order to validate the content of each input query so that they do not contain keywords like "select", "update", "delete" or equivalents.I want to know whether there are better ways to do that.

```
create or replace procedure app_error_test(query1 nvarchar2,
                                           query2 nvarchar2,
                                           query3 nvarchar2,
                                           query4 nvarchar2,
                                           query5 nvarchar2,
                                           query6 nvarchar2) is
queryconcat nvarchar2(30000);
begin

--**************** validate content of input queries

queryconcat := lower(nvl(query1, '') || nvl(query2, '') ||
                     nvl(query3, '') || nvl(query4, '') ||
                     nvl(query5, '') || nvl(query6, ''));

 if (queryconcat like '%drop%' or 
      queryconcat like '%delete%' or
       queryconcat like '%execute%' or 
        queryconcat like '%truncate%' or
         queryconcat like '%create%'  or 
          queryconcat like '%update%'  or
           queryconcat like '%insert%') then

     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20032, 'ILLEGAL CONTENT');
  end if;
end;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `regex_like`:

```
select column_value
     , case
           when regexp_like(' '||column_value||' ','\s(drop|execute|truncate|create|insert|update|delete|merge)\s', 'i')
               then 'Yes'
       end as illegal
from   table(ora_mining_varchar2_nt
             ('drop table customers', 'just dropping by', 'undroppable'));
```

```
COLUMN_VALUE              ILLEGAL
------------------------- -------
drop table customers      Yes
just dropping by          
undroppable
```

I've added `merge` to the list as I assume you are trying to prevent SQL injection. If so, there are still risks even if you filter for keywords. `execute` isn't a SQL keyword, though. Did you mean `call`?

Your procedure would become:

```
create or replace procedure app_error_test
    ( query1 nvarchar2
    , query2 nvarchar2
    , query3 nvarchar2
    , query4 nvarchar2
    , query5 nvarchar2
    , query6 nvarchar2 )
as
    queryconcat nvarchar2(30000) :=
        query1||' '||query2||' '||query3||' '||query4||' '||query5||' '||query6;
begin
    if regexp_like(' ' || queryconcat || ' ', '\s(drop|call|truncate|create|insert|update|delete|merge)\s', 'i')
    then
        raise_application_error(-20032, 'Illegal content in supplied SQL: '||queryconcat);
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I'm trying to understand in . I was wondering if you could tell me more about others risks . You said there are still risks and yes by execute , I mean call.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer a little bit more? It seems like a very good answer but it's a bit complicated for me to understand.Where are the 6 input parameters ?

Comment: By other risks, I was thinking of the scenario where a `select` query is unexpectedly extended to show more than it should. https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/what-is-sql-injection-and-how-to-stop-it

Comment: The `table(ora_mining_varchar2_nt())` part of my query is just to generate some data without creating a table, and the `case` expression is just to make it clear which values match the pattern and which don't. The [`regexp_like()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-D2124F3A-C6E4-4CCA-A40E-2FFCABFD8E19) expression is the main bit.

Comment: Thanks .So what you're saying is that I should have something like this? 
if (regexp_like(queryconcat ,'\s(drop|execute|truncate|create|insert|update|delete|merge)\s', 'i'))
               then
raise_application_error(....)
end if;

???

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've added it to my answer to make it clearer.